# sql joining for query

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a Query

```
SELECT foodjoint_id FROM provider_food_joints WHERE foodjoint_name='".$foodjoint_name."'";
```

Now I have to select all Info from another table which have a foodjoint_id  filed

```
SELECT *  AND foodjoint_name FROM  provider_food_joints  from menu_item where foodjoint_id = THOSE ID
```

I have to join this two

Comment: Yes you have to. Have you tried to read anything about how to compose queries with joins?

Comment: A good starting point is [this article](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).

Comment: @eggyal: I bet OP won't even click it as long as there are ready to use answers

Comment: @zerkms: Don't be so harsh... I've sometimes provided an answer together with that link and had comments back from the OP thanking me for a link to such an easy-to-understand tutorial!  :)

Comment: @eggyal: not even a single word :-) Do you still believe in humanity? ;-)

Comment: @zerkms:  Humanity is an ocean; if a few drops of the ocean are dirty, the ocean does not become dirty.  ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT provider_food_joints.*, 
       menu_item.* 
FROM   provider_food_joints 
       INNER JOIN menu_item 
               ON menu_item.foodjoint_id = provider_food_joints.foodjoint_id 
WHERE  provider_food_joints.foodjoint_name = '".$foodjoint_name."'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM  provider_food_joints a join menu_item b 
on a.foodjoint_id = b.foodjoint_id where foodjoint_name='".$foodjoint_name."'"
```

Answer (score -3):

```
SELECT *  AND foodjoint_name FROM  provider_food_joints  
WHERE foodjoint_id IN (SELECT foodjoint_id FROM provider_food_joints WHERE foodjoint_name='".$foodjoint_name."'")
```